# Using transactions with powershell?

Tags: powershell, transactions

I'm trying to execute the following script:

```
Start-Transaction
Remove-Item D:\sandbox\temp.txt -UseTransaction
Undo-Transaction
```

I keep getting the following error:

```
The provider does not support transactions. Perform the operation again without the -UseTransaction parameter.
At line:3 char:1
+ Remove-Item D:\sandbox\temp.txt -UseTransaction
+ ~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~
    + CategoryInfo          : NotImplemented: (:) [], PSNotSupportedException
    + FullyQualifiedErrorId : NotSupported
```

Anyone know why? I'm using Windows 7 Professional x64 with Powershell 4. D:\ is a local drive.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

From the Get-Help for start-Transaction:

> The cmdlets used in a transaction must be designed to support
>   transactions. Cmdlets that support transactions have a UseTransaction
>   parameter. To perform transactions in a provider, ***the provider must
>   support transactions***. The Windows PowerShell Registry provider in
>   Windows Vista and later versions of Windows supports transactions. You
>   can also use the
>   Microsoft.PowerShell.Commands.Management.TransactedString class to
>   include expressions in transactions on any version of Windows that
>   supports Windows PowerShell. Other Windows PowerShell providers can
>   also support transactions.

*Emphasis added*

I don't believe that the FileSystem provider supports transactions.

Comment: according to https://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/library/hh849765.aspx Remove-Item supports transactions.

Comment: Remove-Item supports transactions ***When used with a provider that supports transactions***. So for instance you should be able to use remove-item as a transaction with the registry provider for instance.

Comment: thanks for the clarification. I know Vista+ added file based transactions to the OS i just assumed incorrectly that Microsofts own cmdlets would support the functionality. Dohhh what luck. They would have been useful.